# How to share git project to other users

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, eclipse, git

I'm learning project sharing for my selenium project using git.
I'm the only person who is working on the project so some things are making me confused.

I have my github account where I have created one repository e.g. AutomationRepository. From Eclipse I have done a push & commit of my code on git successfully by reading some blogs and articles. I'm able to pull, push and commit successfully.

But the thing creating confusion is - suppose another person decides to work with me, then how do I have to change configuration for that user ?

Do I need that person's personal github account and how do I share my project with him?

If the project cloned at the other person's machine then which user's credentials (mine- by using repository created, or the other  person's) do I need to pass while sharing the project?

I want to handle all these from Eclipse, not from the command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Sharing credentials

You should never share your credentials with others. Keep those private. Use the tools provided by git(hub) to give others access to your repository.

## How to give others access

You can invite users to become collaborators to your personal repository.

Repositories owned by an organization can grant more granular access. For more information, see "[Access permissions on GitHub.](https://help.github.com/articles/access-permissions-on-github)"

1. Ask for the username of the person you're inviting as a collaborator. If they don't have a username yet, they can sign up for GitHub.
2. On GitHub, navigate to the main page of the repository.
3. Under your repository name, click Settings.
4. in the left sidebar, click Collaborators.
5. Under "Collaborators", start typing the collaborator's username.
6. Select the collaborator's username
   from the drop-down menu.
7. Click Add collaborator.
8. The user will receive an email inviting them to the repository. Once
   they accept your invitation, they will have collaborator access to
   your repository.

Details: https://help.github.com/articles/inviting-collaborators-to-a-personal-repository/